# Functional Javascript Practice with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, design-patterns

I am currently doing projects in freecodecamp.com to brush up on my javascript skills and just finished a weather report widget. It does the following:

- Gets api from openweathermap.org and displays the weather based on user's latitude and longitude
- Displays the city, weather description and wind speed
- Can toggle between celsius and ferenheit

I want to become a better javascript developer and use best-practice tools and design patterns. Therefore, I would kindly ask if anyone has design pattern suggestions for making my code more efficient, less redundant, and more functional.

Also, the console displays `getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins` why is this, and is there an alternative for getting the user's position from directly from the browser?

The following is my javascript code:

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&APPID=eee5ab7fffb62d126756d9b810ee1875", function(data) {

      var temp = JSON.stringify(data.main.temp);
      //Convert to Ferenheit
      var temp2 = temp * 9 / 5 - 459.67;
      //Round to 2nd decimal place
      var temp3 = Math.round(temp2 * 10) / 10;
      //Display
      $('#temperature').html(temp3 + " F");

      //Description
      var description = data.weather[0].description;

      //Wind speed
      var wind = JSON.stringify(data.wind.speed);

      //HTML disaply
      $(".report").html("<li>" + data.name + "</li>" + "<li>" + description + "</li><li>" + wind + " knots</li>");

      //Toggle Logic
      $('#celsius').on('click', function() {
        var celsius = temp - 273.15;
        var celsius2 = Math.round(celsius * 10) / 10;
        $('#temperature').html(celsius2 + " C");
        $('#celsius').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
        $('#ferenheit').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
      });

      $('#ferenheit').on('click', function() {
        var temp = JSON.stringify(data.main.temp);
        var temp2 = temp * 9 / 5 - 459.67;
        var temp3 = Math.round(temp2 * 10) / 10;
        $('#temperature').html(temp3 + " F");
        $('#ferenheit').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
        $('#celsius').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');

      });

      //Icons logic
      if (description == "broken clouds" || "scattered clouds") {
        $("i").addClass("wi-cloudy");
      } else if (description == "few clouds") {
        $("i").addClass("wi-cloud");
      } else if (description == "clear sky") {
        $("i").addClass("wi-day-sunny");
      } else if (description == "shower rain" || "rain") {
        $("i").addClass("wi-rain");
      } else if (description == "thunderstorm") {
        $("i").addClass("wi-storm-showers");
      } else if (description == "snow") {
        $("i").addClass("wi-snowy");
      } else if (description == "mist") {
        $("i").addClass("wi-dust");
      };

    });

  });

}
```

You can find the rest of my code in the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/aledotgomez/1018b77d1bf84ed76e9a).

Thank you again, and I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: If your code is working try to ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OP wants to get rid of the warnings, I think it belongs here

Comment: Thanks for helping out with the warning, will post this question on codereview (thanks @jcubic)

Answer (score 1):

To work in Chrome, the only way is to run the page from HTTPS.

See https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps/issues/15 and https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

> There are no firm plans at all at this time, other than eventual deprecation.

Comment: I guess they will just follow same policy as for webrtc. EDIT: oops, that's just what is said in your second posted link...